# How to keep <a> "text-decoration: underline" from breaking while applying some positioning to the child <span>?

Tags: html, css, underline, text-decorations

For reasons explained below, I am using relative positioning on `<span>` inside `<a>` in order to slightly change the position of the text wrapped with `<span>` (to place it 2px higher than it's placed automatically). When I do this, obviously, the `text-decoration: underline;` is broken and below my `<span>` it is also starting 2px higher. Please see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qL934xv/

I would like know, if there is a way to make the `<a>` underline run below the `<span>` as well, unbroken and preferably with HTML/CSS only.

**How I came across this problem:**

I am building a bilingual website, where sometimes English words are still in secondary language content. In these cases I wrap these words with `<span lang="en">` and apply corresponding font-family this way:

```
* [lang="en"]
{
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', helvetica;
}
```

However, the font-family I use for my secondary language headings and 'Ropa Sans' do not look nice next to each other and they appear as if "not sitting" on the same line. To fix this, I had been using relative positioning on my `<span>`-s. For example:

```
h1 span {
   position: relative;
   top: -2px;
}
```

This solution worked just fine, before I realized that it messes up with the underline when applied to links. I could avoid using text-decorations on links like these, but I would prefer to know if there is some simple CSS solution that I was not able to identify.

Comment: If fonts don’t fit, don’t use them together. Any need to tune rendering e.g. by lowering or raising glyphs to make fonts fit just indicates they don’t fit. So you are really solving the wrong problem and should ask how to find compatible fonts (which is off-topic at SO, but there are other forums for such problems).

Comment: That's not what he was asking @JukkaK.Korpela

Comment: @Jackhardcastle, that’s why I wrote it as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: But he never said anything about fonts not fitting, his issue was the underline :P Was just random, that's all.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle, “do not look nice next to each other and they appear as if ‘not sitting’ on the same line” surely means misfit.

Comment: Because the underline didn't stay consistent because he'd moved the text up :P @JukkaK.Korpela

Comment: No, that misfit was the cause, moving the text up was an attempt at fixing it.

Comment: I would use different font families if possible, but the problem lies with the secondary language font and I have to choose from a very limited choice, in truth I don't think I have any other option. So it would misfit almost any English font family so I had to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible, but you could do something like

```
a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This works.

Comment: This is a really simple and nice solution, but when using borders instead of text-decoration:underline, it adds up to the overall height of the <a> element, resulting 1px jumping when you hover over such elements. http://jsfiddle.net/8qL934xv/2/

But I think I will be able to work something out of this, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've amended the above for you.